# how can a user on my network browse to a specific named site on my machine?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

I've got 2 sites hosted on my local machine that are under development. They've been configured via a script here at work. I feel like there's a gap in my IIS knowledge because I have no idea how someone not on my localhost can access a specific site. My bindings look like:

```
AlphaSite
  http   siteAlpha  80   * 
  https  siteAlpha  443  *

BetaSite
  http   siteBeta   80   * 
  https  siteBeta   443  *
```

And so on. A user on a different machine can browse to `http://myMachine/theSite/default` which is sending them to `AlphaSite`. I can browse by going to the beta site by going to `http://siteBeta/default`. How can someone that's not on my machine get to `siteBeta`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your betaSite's port to something else eg: 8080. Then you will have

- "http://myMachine/siteAlpha/default"
- "http://myMachine:8080/siteBeta/default"

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that. Changing the port on the SSL gets me a message "The certificate associated with this binding... Editing this bind will cause the HTTPS binding on the other site to be unusable"... so I can't edit the ports without breaking both sites. The site uses SSL almost exclusively.